# How to automate sending DocuSignenvelope

Tags: rest-api, docusign

In Our Org, DocuSign is being used to send documents for esignature related to an Opportunity. Currently, the users have to manually do the following steps which need to be automated for which I need inputs

1. Click on SendwithDocuSign button
2. Add a Document
3. Add the recipients
4. Click on the Send button

My Analysis:
- onClick of SendwithDocuSign is calling a managed apex class.
- As DocuSign is not within salesforce, I believe that this requirement could be achievable only with calling the DocuSign APIs. I have tried searching for the APIs in google/Docusign and not able to find the relevant one. If my understanding is correct, please point me to the right API if not advise on how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: We use the DocGen package which has a built-in integration with DocuSign. It took some work to get it all functioning together, but they expose global Apex classes that can be used to automatically trigger the docusign integration. I assume you don't need document generation capabilities, but in case that's part of your use case, you might check them out:

https://www.nintex.com/workflow-automation/document-generation/

Comment: Hi Nathanael, Thanks for your response. Yes, the document templates are already in place. In the automation, I believe I need to pass the right document id to the API and the recipients related to the source object which is Opportunity. Also, it seems DocGen is a paid app which will not work for me. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Nah, you're right. That's why I just made it a comment instead of an answer; doesn't help your direct question, but on the off-chance that solution met your needs (or the needs of someone googling around later), I figured I'd mention having success with it :-)